# How can i solve this break label problem?

Tags: java, label, break

im getting crazy now about the java break label. I tried everything but when i try running my code, the break label just close the console... here is my code, it would be really nice if someone point me in the right direction.
Thank you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int choix1A;
    int choix2A;
    int choix3A;
    int choix1B;
    int choix2B;
    int choix3B;
    String choixA = "";
    String choixB = "";
    String choixC = "";
        
    
    
    menuPrincipal:
    {
        do
    {
        
    System.out.println("*****Veuillez choisir votre département:*****");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------\n");
    System.out.println("C - Département de commerce");
    System.out.println("P - Département de production");
    System.out.println("E - Sortir du programme");
    
    Scanner lireChoixA = new Scanner(System.in);
    choixA = lireChoixA.nextLine(); 
    choix1A = choixA.compareTo("c");
    choix2A = choixA.compareTo("p");
    choix3A = choixA.compareTo("e");        
    }
         
        
    while(choix1A != 0 && choix2A != 0 && choix3A !=0);
    
    
    
    switch (choixA) 
    
    {
        case "c":
            System.out.println("R - Si vous êtes un représentant");
            System.out.println("V - Si vous êtes un vendeur");
            System.out.println("E - Pour le menu principal");
            Scanner lireChoixB = new Scanner(System.in);
            choixB = lireChoixB.nextLine();
            choix1B = choixB.compareTo("r");
            choix2B = choixB.compareTo("v");
            choix3B = choixB.compareTo("e");    
        
            if(choix3B == 0)
            {
                break menuPrincipal;
            }
    
      case "p":
            System.out.println("P - Si vous êtes un producteur");
            System.out.println("M - Si vous êtes affectés à la manutention");
            System.out.println("E - Pour le menu principal");
        break;
      case "e":
          System. exit(0);
        break;
    }
    }
```

I try to break that switch case with the label menuPrincipal but it keep closing the console instead of jumping to the label listed

Comment: I've written Java for over 10 years and I've never found a compelling use for that feature. Not once. If it's confusing you then just don't use it.

Comment: my mistake, ignore

Comment: In your code, the break leaves the scope of the label which then leads to program exit (there is no code after the block as posted anyways).

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. The `break` statement does not "jump to the label listed", it terminates the labeled statement.

From the [Java Language Specification: break statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15):

> A break statement with label Identifier attempts to transfer control to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same Identifier as its label; **this statement, which is called the break target, then immediately completes normally**. In this case, the break target need not be a switch, while, do, or for statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact logic you want for how your menu flows, but this could be a better alternative.  It'll loop through the menu until you tell it to exit based on whatever conditions you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean exitMenu = false;
    int choix1B;
    int choix2B;
    int choix3B;
    String choixA = "";
    String choixB = "";
    String choixC = "";
    


    do
    {
    
        System.out.println("*****Veuillez choisir votre département:*****");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("C - Département de commerce");
        System.out.println("P - Département de production");
        System.out.println("E - Sortir du programme");

        Scanner lireChoixA = new Scanner(System.in);
        choixA = lireChoixA.nextLine().toLowerCase(); 
        
    

        switch (choixA) {
            case "c":
                System.out.println("R - Si vous êtes un représentant");
                System.out.println("V - Si vous êtes un vendeur");
                System.out.println("E - Pour le menu principal");
                Scanner lireChoixB = new Scanner(System.in);
                choixB = lireChoixB.nextLine().toLowerCase(); 
                
                
                if(choixB.equals("e"))
                {
                    exitMenu = true;
                }
    
            case "p":
                System.out.println("P - Si vous êtes un producteur");
                System.out.println("M - Si vous êtes affectés à la manutention");
                System.out.println("E - Pour le menu principal");
                break;
              case "e":
                exitMenu = true;
                break;
        }
    }while(exitMenu == false);
    
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all i appreciate your answers. I'm beggining my class of prog 2 month ago so your answers helped me alot

thanks